# Change CLI PHP version

Tags: php, centos7, virtualmin

I have a server "CentOS 7" managed by virtualmin, my web server PHP Version is 7.2.24, but the Command Line Interface (CLI) reading PHP Version => 5.4.16

I have tried several methods to change the CLI to 7.2.24, but all of them failed

Method 1
From virtualmin changed the server template as below (Mode was 'FCGId')
[image]

Methods 2

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2.24
```

but all of the above failed after rebooting the server.

Answer (score 0):

When installing PHP 7.x via RPM, there shouldn't be any PHP 5.x to begin with.

Just see which priority it has an give it a lower number:

```
 update-alternatives --query php
 update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php7.2.24 php 10
```

One can also set it manually:

```
update-alternatives --config php
```